# Slide JQUERY 100% tela EXEMPLO

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estou fazendo um slide em tela full, más me deparo que em outros monitores a imagem e o texto fica maiores/menores. Gostaria de deixar ele tamanho único.

Vi [este site](http://www.studioead.com.br/Demo_comunicacao_07-10-16/index.html) abaixo, achei muito interessante. Percebe-se que mesmo aumentando/diminuindo o zoom os textos e imagem permanecem fixo.

Alguém tem uma sugestão para mim?

Comment: Isso é um e-learning. Parece que foi feito no Edge, Articulate ou Captivate.

Answer (score 0):

Jogue o seguinte css na div da imagem:

```
.imagem{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Width 100% fará com que a imagem pegue toda a largura da tela, o height 100vh, fará com que será pego toda a altura da tela, indiferente do tamanho, 100vh, são 100 pontos da tela, caso tenha dúvidas sobre vh [Clique aqui](http://brasa.art.br/2015/dicas-e-truques-htmlcssjs/vw-e-vh-unidades-de-medida-para-css-matadoras/).

Background-size cover fará com que a imagem se ajuste ao tamanho inserido, background position center irá mantê-la no meio da tela e o background-repeat fará com que a imagem não repita, seja exibida somente uma vez.

Lembrando que a imagem deverá estar de fundo, exemplo:

```
<div class="imagem" style="background-image: url(localimagem/imagem.jpg);"></div>
```